# K-Means Clustering Profile Plot & Data Normalization

Tags: r, clustering, unsupervised-learning, k-means, normalization

I am new to k-means clustering and I am working on a project on cryptoanalysis. I have a few questions and I hope to get some help here.

1. I have four variables and my variables data values can range from -100% to 100% (as of now, the data I used currently range from -40% to 5%), do I still need to normalize the data? If yes, do I use z-score normalization?
2. If I did to normalize data in market capitalization of an asset, how do I go about doing it?
3. Usually, in examples, the k-means clustering runs on 2 variables and you can plot the clusters in the x-axis and y-axis. In this case, I have 4 variables how do I go about plotting the clusters in a chart?
4. I have tried to run k-means with 4 clusters and plot 2 profile plot: 1st plot). My data are not normalized before running k-means, 2nd plot) My data are all z-score normalized before running k-mean. The 2nd plot looks wrong as cluster 2 & 4 looks like a straight line and the two profile plot looks very different after I did the z-score normalization. Did anyone get any advice?

   - 1st plot (No normalization)

[image]

- 2nd plot (Z-Score normalization)

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to get from running the Kmeans on 4 features?

Comment: Hi Carlos, thank you for your reply. i am trying to get the cluster (group of cryptos) that contains strong momentum and trend technical indicators values (e.g. cluster 1 from the plot). Each of the features is a technical indicator such as moving average.

Comment: What are these plots of? What is the y-axis? What is “index”? How did you decide on 4 clusters?

Comment: Hi Bapowell, thank you for your reply. These plots are profile of each cluster where the x-axis are the technical indicators (Index 1 - short term moving average , 2 - long term moving average , 3 - Short term rate of change, 4- long term rate of change) and the y axis are the percentage of the current price movement over or below the technical indcators (e.g. if the price is 50, the short term moving average is 40 then the value is (50-40)/40 * 100 = 25%). For the 4 clusters, i haven't do an elbow plot to decide the number of clusters so i just fix it to 4 at the moment.

Comment: Ok. Generally speaking z-score standardization is a good idea. As for visualizing higher-dimensional clusters in 2D, the short answer is: you can’t. Try a dimensionality reduction technique like LDA, which will allow you to project your clusters down to 2D.